# Reading file extensions in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a load of .doc files that I need to read the file extension and tell if .doc is [Word DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_Word#Word_1990_to_1995) or [Office 97](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_Word#Word_97) or [Office 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2003). I can't find a way of doing this.

Is it possible? If so, how can I do this in VB.NET?

Comment: You could load the .doc file as plain text and search for the version information, this will be the last version of Word used that saved the document, more info can be found here: [Determining Word Versions of Documents](http://word.tips.net/T000601_Determining_Word_Versions_of_Documents.html)

Comment: I think is better to use a third party library to open the file and get its version eg. http://www.devtriogroup.com/WordReader/Default.aspx or others ww.syncfusion.com/products/aspnet/docio#processing-doc-files_heading

Comment: If you get enough info from just the file extension - last 3/4 letters - you can just test using string functions (.EndsWith)